# Print comma separated value in BASH

Tags: bash

How would one go about printing a comma separated value without the comma. 
For example

```
John,Smith
```

would print out

```
John Smith
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd choose [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) as my weapon. To be more specific I'd use the [search and replace feature](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) of bash parameter expansion.

```
$ name="John,Smith"
$ echo "${name/,/ }"
John Smith
```

Comment: A very good point, since the current "implementation" only replaces the first occurrence of ",".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're reading from a file:

```
while IFS=, read -ra names; do
    echo "${names[*]}"
done < file
```

The first line iterates over the lines of the file, reading each line into the array "names", using comma as the field separator. The IFS variable is set only for the duration of the read command. Then the array is joined into a single string, using the first char of the default value of IFS (a space) as the join characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use tr to replace commas with spaces?

```
echo 'John,Smith' | tr ',' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the comma with a space character. Common tools for this is either sed or tr:

```
NAME="John,Smith"
echo $NAME | tr , ' '
echo $NAME | sed 's/,/ /g'
```